# How can I store mathematical formulas with django

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I'm working on a calculator that uses some mathematical formulas produced with multi linear regression. The problem here is this formulas should be constructed in dynamic way. With the admin interface the user can update and create formulas. The issue is how to model f= a0 +a1x + a2x^2.... and save all the data on the database(coefficients).
And in the future we will have complex formulas for example a formula that includes(exponential functions, sin, cos...) . Is there like a library or better way to model the application to support these features.

Comment: If you're only modelling polynomial functions, then saving a list of coefficients in an ArrayField (with 0's where the exponent is not present) would be the most straightforward option, then for each item in the list, `value * x^index` does the trick. But you're saying you want to model **any** function?

Comment: Define “complex formulas”. We need a sense of what you are doing here.

Comment: Thank you I didn't know about the ArrayField I thin that's the solution for polynomial formulas.

Comment: ArrayField is only supported on PostgreSQL, but it's also quite easy to implement yourself (if you use a different db) on top of a CharField, using json.loads() and json.dumps().

Comment: Ok I'll start the implementation with ArratField